# How to update a legacy concrete5 package

Tags: php, package, concrete5, concrete5-8.x, concrete5-5.6

A long long time ago, I've developed a concrete5 package for concrete5 <= 5.6 for a small non-profit organization. Now, because it has never been upgraded, there are some issues that I can't easily fix, related to the old PHP version. Therefore, I'd like to migrate the web site to a new installation of concrete5 version 8. However, for a fresh install of the latest concrete5, of course my old plugin no longer works. What are the steps to update a legacy concrete5 package to work under the newer concrete5 versions? I couldn't find any info or guides online unfortunately. I have looked at the new documentation on how to develop a package for concrete5 8, but found it very scant. I've changed the namespace of my controller for example, but this is not enough to let the package function. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: the code is [here](https://github.com/rbnvrw/cottage-booker)

Comment: It is a really big field you asked for. Your package contains a block, a job, mail templates, a single page and more. So you need to migrate every part into the c5-8 system. And the good thing is, for all of these parts a doc exists. So in short: think the migration as a redo of a package. - As I can see, you are still using `lib` and `models` folders. These classes should be in a `/src` folder (`/twig` should also be there). To have a look into the deprecation page is also recommended, in addition to the pages here: https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/packages/overview.

Answer (score 0):

The folder and file structure is mostly the same. YOu have to use namespacing in your classes now. Package controllers have changed a bit in what they extend I think. BLocks are mostly the same. Using JS and CSS assets still works the old way if you prefer but there's a new and better way with asset management.

Feel free to contact me by PM on the concrete5 website my username is mnakalay. There you can tell me more about your package and what it contains (blocks, attributes...) and I can give you a few pointers

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you could give some pointers in your answer, so I can accept it and others can benefit as well? If you are interested, the code of the package is here: https://github.com/rbnvrw/cottage-booker